# Toggle sliding animation on same div when clicking on two different buttons with React and Keyframes

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, slide

I was searching some similar issue here but couldn't find it.
I want to slide a div that have two buttons. So on click on the left button the div should slide to the right and if I click again it should toggle or slide to the left, same goes for the right button, when it's clicked the div should go left and other way around.

This is done with keyFrames.

```
 .slideLeft {
  animation: slide-left 0.8s;
 }

 .slideRight {
  animation: slide-right 0.8s;
 }
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I click on the left div let's say, it's adding a classname slideRight and the div is sliding to the right side, and if I click again it will slide it to the left side and will add classname slideLeft. Now when I want to slide the div to the left side if I click on the right button, the classname slideLeft is already there and the animation is not happening.
I hope I explained the issue well :)), here are some snippets of the code:

How I'm keeping the state:

```
  const [openAboutSection, setOpenAboutSection] = useState(false);
  const [openWorksSection, setOpenWorksSection] = useState(false);

  const openAboutHandler = () => {
      setOpenAboutSection(!openAboutSection);
      setOpenWorksSection(false);
  };

  const openWorksHandler = () => {
     setOpenWorksSection(!openWorksSection);
     setOpenAboutSection(false);
  };
```

How the classnames are added:

```
 <Home
    projects={projects}
    className={`${openAboutSection ? "slideRight" : "slideLeft"} 
    ${openWorksSection ? "slideLeft" : "slideRight"}`}
    openAbout={openAboutSection}
    openWorks={openWorksSection}
    onOpenAboutHandler={openAboutHandler}
    onOpenWorksHandler={openWorksHandler}
  />
```

Snippet from home component for your reference:

```
    <div>
          <button
            onClick={onOpenAboutHandler}>
            {"about"}
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={onOpenWorksHandler}>
            {"works"}
          </button>
    </div>
```